# Why is RegionSymmetricDifference failing?

Tags: regions

I've been working with some simple polygon regions. When I use `RegionSymmetricDifference` with these simple 3D regions, it doesn't return an error message, but it fails to return what I expect. Here is what I'm seeing:

```
p1 = Polygon[N@CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 6]];
p2 = Polygon[N@CirclePoints[{0.5, 0}, 6]];
reg4 = BoundaryMesh[
  RegionProduct[p1, MeshRegion[{{0}, {1.}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]]
reg5 = BoundaryMesh[
  RegionProduct[p2, MeshRegion[{{0}, {1}}, Line[{1, 2}]]]]
```

[image: Polygons 3D Image]

Here is the result of running `RegionSymmetricDifference`:

```
reg6 = RegionSymmetricDifference[reg4, reg5]
```

[image: RegionSymmetricDifference Image]

As can be seen, all that returns is a BooleanRegion that is unevaluated. However, if I run `RegionDifference`, the expected region is returned.

```
reg7 = RegionDifference[reg4, reg5]
```

[image: RegionDifference Image]

If I run `RegionSymmetricDifference` on a pair of 2D polgons, it returns what I expect is the correct result:

```
RegionSymmetricDifference[p1, p2]
```

[image: RegionSymmetricDifference Image 2D]

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the usage of `RegionSymmetricDifference`?

In the case where `BooleanRegion` is returned unevaluated, it should be possible to wrap the expression inside `Region` in order to see the region. The following is what I see. There is an error message, but the kernel continues to run. I didn't wait for it to timeout. I aborted after about 60 seconds.

```
Region[reg6]
```

[image: Wrapped in Region image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted this issue to WRI support. They were able to reproduce the problem and have passed it along to the developers. I'm not sure if this affects versions other than 11.2. I the mean time, I will use RegionDifference.

Answer (score 4):

[`RegionSymmetricDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionSymmetricDifference) is having an issue with the fact that one of the pieces is an empty region. Since as you noted, [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference) is working fine, you can work around this issue with:

```
RegionUnion[
    RegionDifference[reg4, reg5],
    RegionDifference[reg5, reg4]
]
```

[image]

It might be worthwhile reporting this to support.

Comment: yes, I was thinking I might need to report it to support. I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else has more information to add.